# Search file with Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, search

I have following recursive Search-Function:

```
public List<FileInfo> Search_Files(String strDir, String line)
{
    List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

    try
    {
         foreach (String strFile in Directory.GetFiles(strDir,line+r))
         {
             files.Add(new FileInfo(strFile));
         }

         foreach (String strSubDir in Directory.GetDirectories(strDir))
         {
             List<FileInfo> sublist = Search_Files(strSubDir, line);

             foreach (FileInfo file_infow in sublist)
             {
                 files.Add(file_infow);
             }
         }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         ...
    }

    return (files);
}
```

The line variable's value looks like "1234".
Now I wanted to search for files like: 1234c.something or 1234.something

I created following Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[a-z].* | .*");
```

I added it to line string, but it doesn't work.  Why does this not work and how can I correct this?

Comment: You can't pass a regex to `.GetDirectories`. Try `1234c.*` (here, `.` is a literal dot, and `*` means *any number of characters*). Do not forget to change the signature to `public List<FileInfo> Search_Files(String strDir, String line, String r)` and if `line` is `1234`, then `r` must be `c.*`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't want to only to find the c.* files i want to find the 1234[a-z].* files.

Comment: I see, I posted an answer, hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) methods accept a *searchPattern* that is *not* a regex.

> The search string to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (`*` and `?`) characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular expressions.

You can filter the results with the following regex:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\d{4}.*");
// var r = new Regex(@"^\d{4}.*"); // Use this if file names should start with the 4 digits.
files.Add(Directory.GetFiles(strDir)
            .Where(p => r.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(p)))
            .ToList());
```

The `\d{4}.*` regex matches 4 digits (`\d{4}`) and any 0 or more characters but a newline.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my situation...
The filename isn't only 1234...
It could be 123455, 99993, 324...

and now I want to get every version of this id's.
The versions which are possible FOR EXAMPLE for the string line "1111" are following two:
1111[a-z].anything and 1111.anything

the second one is no problem: foreach (String strFile in Directory.GetFiles(strDir,line+".*"))

But I don't know how to find the first ones.

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string and a regex object, that is what you did. As for the regex, you can use `\d+` instead of a number. If you need to match just 4 numbers, use `\d{4}`. If you plan to allow the 2 patterns above, the pattern is still identical: `\d{4}.*` because `[a-z]` is optional, right?

Comment: I have changed the answer, please take a look (now, only the filename is checked against the pattern. Also, if you plan to get the files that **start with** the numbers+something, you need to add `^` at the beginning of the pattern. If you have a problem with correct regex for the files you need to match, just drop me a comment. You can check the patterns at [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester).

Answer (score 1):

i used `LINQ`, give it a try

```
string[] allFiles =  Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Files");
List<string> neededFiles = (from c in allFiles
                               where Path.GetFileName(c).StartsWith("fileStartName")
                               select c).ToList<string>();

foreach (var file in neededFiles)
{
   // do the tesk you want with the matching files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the '.' you have to escape it as '\.'. '.*' by itself means any character n-times. Have a look here for the specifics about formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

I would also suggest that you use a more strict regular expression. If you know that your file name starts by 1234, use it in the regular expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.  The first is to use a windows search filter.  This is what you can pass directly to the `GetFiles()` method.  (`EnumerateFiles()` does the same thing, and might be faster in this case, but that's irrelevant to your question).

A windows search pattern uses `*` to represent 'any number of any character' and `?` is used to represent a single unknown character.  These are not actually regular expressions.

You can then perform a search like this:

```
return Directory.EnumerateFiles(strDir, line + "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
                .ToList();
```

The second is what you were originally looking for and that's performing a linq query with actual regular expressions.  That can be done like this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(line + @".*\..*") 
// regex says use line, then anything any number of times, 
// and then a dot and then any chars any amount of times

return Directory.EnumerateFiles(strDir, *.*, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => pattern.IsMatch(f))
                .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
                .ToList();
```

**Note:**  The above two examples show how to also convert the provided strings to FileInfo objects like the signature of your Search_Files method requires in the "linq-way."  Also I'm using the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` flag that performs the recursive search for you, without you needing to write your own.

As for why your originally posted method did not work; there are two issues with it.

1. You are attempting to concatenate a regex object with a string.  This is not possible because you are looking to concat the regex *pattern* with the string.  This should be done before (or inside of) the construction of the regex object as I showed in my example.
2. Assuming you did not attempt to concat a regex object with a string, the Regex pattern that you are using pretty much would match anything, always.  This would not limit anything down.

Comment: Thank you but I knew this solution before.
The Problem is that there are files like (if i search for "1234"):
12344256754325.something
I don't want to get this files!
With your method I get this files also...

Comment: Can you please be more clear in the exact pattern of the file names?  Using my second option above would work for you, but you'd need to refine the regular expression to match better.